# Disable bootstrap tooltip on touch devices

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, touch, tooltip, user-experience

I would like to disable Bootstrap tooltips on touch devices.

Since my tooltips are triggered on hover, a user on a touch device must tap once to see the tooltip and then tap again to activate the button.

The default behavior for other programs is simply shutting off the tooltips on touch devices (eg: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/full-featured/). I would like to do the same.

How can I do this? (I would prefer to still use Bootstrap tooltips but will also listen to suggestions not using Bootstrap tooltips).

I tried adding the follwing jQuery:

```
if (!("ontouchstart" in window)) {
    $("#tooltip").tooltip();
}
```

However, this doesn't work on Chrome (Chrome detects my desktop as a touch device, see: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=557565).

This issue has been discussed (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6232) but I haven't found a solution that works.

Thanks.